# Remove Leading spaces in exported CSV file

Tags: csv, ssis

I created a Data Flow Task that generates a CSV file from Database.
The CSV file has a zip column.Some rows are having zip like "43218-2166" and few are having zip  like "21709".
The problem here is for the columns with zip length=5, alignment is right.I want these Zips to be text aligned left.
Otherwise Execute Process Task which takes this CSV as input does not work fine.
I created a Derived Column between OLEDB Source and Flat File Destination and used several expressions on zip including LTRIM,RTRIM , REPLACE etc.
Nothing worked.
Please suggest if any workaround to get the left alignment in CSV for Zip?

[image: Below image shows how the Zips are arranged.]

Comment: To remove leading spaces, you should use LTRIM(), not RTRIM().

Comment: just typo ..Tried LTRIM(), but not worked.

Comment: what you mean by aligning :D its looks like you open this csv in Excel and it recognize this 5 digits as number. If you want to see this data as text add single comma `'` in front of this numbers. Doesn't look like SSIS problem to me :D

Comment: Never mind, I mis-read the question.  I thought you were importing from a CSV, but you are exporting to a CSV.   In this case Ako's answer is probably the correct one.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is that when you open a file in Excel it show '21709' as a number, so right aligned 
and '50301-0100' as text, therefore left aligned.

In csv itself you can not define an alignment.

I tested with next csv file.

```
A,B,X
1,2,X
1   ,2,X
1,   2,X
111-111   ,222-222,X
111-111,   222-222,X
111-111,222-222,X
111-111,222-222,X
```

To force a left align, you can do something ugly like putting a apostroph  before every number.

Comment: You can put spaces before or after a value in a csv.

Comment: Putting spaces I agree, but it did not change my Excel behavior, all numbers are aligned right.

Comment: Tab ,I did not get it.Can you plz elaborate how to implement it?

Comment: Ako ,I did not get your answer.What I could do to left align all my Zip columns in excel ?Plz elaborate.

Comment: I added one more line to the answer. Putting a ' in front of every number will help. But you will see it back in Excel.

Comment: That does not help Ako.It will fail running Execute Process Task as input CSV has incorrect Zip format.

Comment: If I understand correctly you want two different things, a csv that displays data with alignment and a pure csv that contains the data. Why is the alignment in Excel important? Can you put the zipcode in one csv with two columns, one aligned and one pure data? Or can you create two files ?

Comment: We have only 1 CSV file.The output CSV generated will act as argument to Execute process task.I need all zips left aligned as the task is not working as expected if zips are improperly assigned.

Comment: Again, csv does not have alignment, it is nothing more than some values separated by comma's. If the task does not like it, than the problem is not alignment.

Comment: I agree.But its confusing.when i right align zips and pass argument ,output is fine.Other wise output csv resulted by execute process task is not loading properly.The message while opening is "File not loaded completely"

Comment: So align in Excel and save it again, that changes the content of the csv file? Can you post the file before and after ?

Comment: It seems the only issue is with Excels auto format feature.Everything is fine at SSIS end.I have opened output CSV in Notepad++ and found data correctly.Thanks a lot Ako for all the time and patience.

Answer (score 0):

You could open the file in Excel, select the zip column and then format the entire column as text. But I guess you don't want to do this every time you regenerate your file.

So you could quote the values (that is: enclose each value within quote characters on both sides) that might otherwise wrongly be interpreted as number.
Since your file is generated, easiest would be to quote **all** text fields, at least for the zip column. The other two columns are fine, since Excel can see these aren't numbers.

What exactly is take to be the quote character depends. In Libre Office Calc, when I open a csv file, I get a dialog to specify field separators and quoting character. So here you could choose apostrophe, backtick or whatever you want. Whatever you input there obviously has to match with your file.